# How to load a new version of model/file in a running spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a sparkML model which i am using for predictions on a streaming data. However there are continuous updates to the model based on the feedback from shareholders.

Model is stored at a s3 location. I checked and in structured streaming models are loaded from a s3 location at the start of the job, and the job is oblivious to changes made at that location unless it is restarted.

Is there a way to load the new version without restarting the streaming job ? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: how are you loading currently model in streaming job and using it? please add pseudo steps.

Comment: I am using pipeline in sparkML to develop models. It's a simple CrossValidtorModel.save and then CrossValidatorModel.read.load(Constants.classificationModelPath) for a streaming job. However, this loads model only at the beginning of the job and updates won't be reflected unless the streaming job is restarted

Comment: I see, do you load model within transformation like mapPartitions or action like foreachRDD? I am just trying to understand how you use model in streaming.

Comment: No, with structured streaming it can directly be loaded as an instance of CrossValidatorModel class. The instance can then be used for predictions